# Meaning of light prompts on Ender 6 motherboard

Tags: repair, creality-ender-6

What are the meanings of the **red**, **green**, and **blue** light prompts on the Ender 6 motherboard? My Ender 6 is stuck at the boot screen. I followed the instructions provided in the "Creality After-Sale" videos on YouTube and took apart the base of the printer to look if any wiring was loose.

I found that the red light was continuously on at the D2 position on the motherboard. Creality's video showed the light on this location of the motherboard to be blue. I also checked on the internet and it appears some users also have a green light. Users also report the light blinks but in my case, it remains red throughout.

I am wondering if this indicates what is wrong with my printer and why it is stuck on the boot screen.

Comment: A good clear photo of the LEDs *might* help (although I've included a screenshot from the manual, in my non-answer below). I believe that there is also an LED at D4 - are there any others? Also, please [edit] your question and provide a link to the Creality video to which you refer which shows the blue light. Are you sure that the blue and green lights are for (a) the same printer/motherboard, and (b) the same LED location (and not a different LED, such as D4)?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this problem? If so, please post an answer, as it could be useful to others.

Comment: @Greenonline, I did. The motherboard was fried. Changing it resolved the problem.

Comment: Ah, good. If you could post a simple answer and mark it as the accepted answer that would be great (just to remove the question from the unanswered queue). Thanks. Did you ever find out the meanings of the LED colours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the motherboard had gotten damaged and the green light indication had to do with showcasing this. The problem was resolved when I bought a new motherboard online and replaced the damaged motherboard with the new one. The printer works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a bit of a non-answer, and I've posted it only because:*

- *it was too long for a comment, and;*
- *to provide some info in order to save people having to pointlessly search for data that isn't actually available in the manual.*

---

Apparently you aren't the only person with similar issues relating to understanding the meaning of the LEDs - Creality appear to be not very good at providing info about these LEDs... see this page on Reddit, [Ender 6 motherboard lights](https://www.reddit.com/r/ender6/comments/ulr3pw/ender_6_motherboard_lights/).

The [user guide (on manualshelf.com)](https://www.manualshelf.com/manual/creality/prcr-1011/instructions-english.html) doesn't mention the LEDs at all. I flicked through all of it and the most useful page was [page 29](https://www.manualshelf.com/manual/creality/prcr-1011/instructions-english/page-29.html) which showed the motherboard but (again) there was no mention of the LEDs:

[image: Ender 6 controller board]

For reference, the LEDs at located thusly:

- D2 is on the left hand side of the board to the left of the heatsink.
- D4 is on the right hand side, just behind the USB socket

[image: Ender 6 controller board (annotated)]

FWIW, D2 seems to be red when powered on, as mentioned in [this post](https://forum.creality.com/post/4518) and [this post](https://forum.creality.com/post/4612) on [My Creality Ender-6 is stuck at the boot screen with the white status bar](https://forum.creality.com/topic/1469/my-creality-ender-6-is-stuck-at-the-boot-screen-with-the-white-status-bar?lang=en-US).

---

You may need to issue a [service request](https://www.creality.com/service-request)... if you do so, and get a response, please post an answer as it would probably be of benefit to others.